# Delphi and Access: EDatabaseError: Field not Found

Tags: delphi

I have a project base on Delphi and Access. I have renaimed a column name in access table, also I have changed it in all places in project, and in all SQL - requests, which use it. And when I call ADOQuery (ADOQuery.Open), which uses that column name, I get error: "EDatabaseError: Field not Found", and besides, that field name, which isn't found, is old, and it nowhere uses! How can it be? May be, it needs update somehow?

Comment: Do you have persistent fields on your ADOQuery?  Maybe there's one with the old field name ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to execute the query with "select * from your_table_name" from new clear ADOQuery component (without field properties) from your delphi project, to see the actual result structure. May be some misprints in access data or in filed difinitions in delphi project

Or try to search the field name in delphi dfm resources

Answer (score 2):

If you use db-aware components, i guess one of those is still pointing to the old fieldname.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the form or datamodule that contains your ADOQuery1.  Choose "View as text" from the pop-up menu.

You can then do a search through the text to find where the old version of the field name occurs.  Once you have, right click the text window, select "View as form" from the pop-up menu and edit the component that contains the old field name.

Answer (score 0):

Select you TADOQuery component on the form or data module. You will see a property called "Parameters". Double click on the property editor and then you will see a list of all of the parameters that have been added to the component. One of those will be the field that is no longer in use. You can select the field and then delete it.